# How to replace commas with spaces in XSL

Tags: xslt

I need to replace every other comma with a space in my XML output. Right now, I have latitude and longitude that looks like this:

```
-0.52437106918239,0.391509433962264,-0.533805031446541,0.430817610062893,0 
-0.547955974842767,0.427672955974843,
```

I need the coordinates in my XML output to look like this:

```
-0.52437106918239 0.391509433962264, -0.533805031446541 0.430817610062893,0   
-0.547955974842767 0.427672955974843
```

How can I use XSLT to do this? Here is my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Placemark/kml:Polygon  
/kml:outerBoundaryIs/kml:LinearRing"/>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="kml:LinearRing">
"POLYGON((<xsl:value-of select="kml:coordinates"/>))"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 it would be trivial. You could use [replace()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace).

In XSLT 1.0, you could use template like so. Call the convert-space template on your list that needs every second comma replaced.

```
<xsl:template name="convert-space">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,',')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,',')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="convert-comma">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="convert-comma">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,',')">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,',')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="convert-space">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```