# how to replace comma with space in an xml element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<Report_Entry>
<Employee_ID> 1 </Employee_ID>
<First_Name>John</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Smith</Last_Name>
<Primary_Address>4200 Holly Hall Street, #18</Primary_Address>
<Hire_Date>2000-01-02-08:00</Hire_Date>
</Report_Entry>

<Report_Entry>
<Employee_ID> 2 </Employee_ID>
<First_Name>Julie</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Ray</Last_Name>
<Primary_Address>255 Gregor Street</Primary_Address>
<Hire_Date>2000-05-01-08:00</Hire_Date>
</Report_Entry>
```

I have 500 such report entry elements. I want to have the output as:

> 1, John, Smith, 4200 Holly Hall Street #18, 01-02-2000
>   2, Julie, Ray, 255 Gregor Street, 05-01-2000
>   and so on......

Here is the XSLT code that I wrote to transform the above XML:

```
<!-- language: lang-xslt -->
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
<xsl:for-each select="*">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
              <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
          </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>   

</xsl:template>
```

I am unable to accomplish 2 things:

1. I want to replace every comma in Primary_Address element with a space
2. Change the date format of Hire_Date element to the desired format (mm-dd-yyyy)

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me out in solving the above two issues.....

Comment: Check if [**this SO post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898952/how-to-replace-commas-with-spaces-in-xsl) helps for the first item.

Comment: @Harry Hey Harry, I am unable to understand the code in the link you suggested. Can you please let me know about how do I make changes to my existing xslt?

Answer (score 1):

To replace a comma with a space you can make use of the [translate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., ',', ' ')"/>
```

Be wary though, if you have not seen this function before, as it does not work in quite the same way as a normal 'replace' function does. It only translates single characters into other characters. It does not replace matching strings with othe strings. (Note, if you are using XSLT 2.0, there is a 'replace' function available).

As for formatting the date, you could use the substring function here to re-arrage the field, assuming the Hire_Date was always in the same format.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 6, 2), '-', substring(., 9, 2), '-' , substring(., 1, 4))"/>
```

One thing to note, it might be worth re-arranging your XSLT to use templates instead of an **xsl:for-each**. This would help with writing the code for the Hire_Date as it would be in its own template. Additionally, if **Hire_Date** was always going to be the last element, this would allow you to drop the **xsl:if** test on the position.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Report_Entry/*[not(self::Hire_Date)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., ',', ' ')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Hire_Date">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 6, 2), '-', substring(., 9, 2), '-' , substring(., 1, 4))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```